# How to rectify Cannot find symbol error in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have Created one LWUIT Application Which writes the Fonts on the Component when I press Mobile Keys(like If i press key 2 then it 
will Display 2 on the screen).I am using switch case to do that.

For Example,

```
public void keyPressed(int key)
 {
   // some codes here .....
   switch(key)
        {
           case KEY_NUM0:
                    // some code to write 0 on the screen and breaks;
           case KEY_NUM1:
                    // some code to write 1 on the screen and breaks;
                            :
                            :
                            :
         }
 }
```

I tried with like this code.while compiling it shows,

```
     C:\Documents and Settings\Rtbi\j2mewtk\2.5.2\apps\javaForm1\src\javaForm.java:185: 
cannot find symbol
     symbol  : variable KEY_NUM0
     location: class javaForm
                    case KEY_NUM0:
```

how can i resolve this problem.Do I need to import some other header files apart from,

```
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;` and when you call the keys use `Canvas.KEY_NUM0`, etc.

Comment: While this is true generally we just recommend using '0' instead of KEY_NUM0 etc. The constant's for these values are somewhat redundant.